# how to create checkbox events that call jQuery functions on other pages?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I'm wanting a checkbox in theme.php to trigger a function in front.php
that changes a css file from default with a white background to blue with a blue background.
Unchecking the checkbox reverts it back to default.
I've tried various different methods from having the script in theme.php to moving it to front.php using all the different jQuery functions including load, change, click, post, using if/else, appending to the header tags in front.php...
nothing works.
in theme.php

```
<div class="main-content">
    <input type="checkbox" id="front"/>
    <label for="front">FrontEnd</label>
</div>
```

and in front.php

```
const frontEnd = document.querySelector("#front");
frontEnd.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if(frontEnd.checked){
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.href = "css/blue.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
    }else{
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.href = "css/default.css";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
    }
});
```

any tips on what I may be missing?
cheers.

Comment: *"call functions on other pages"*. You can't. When you leave a page all it's script is gone and whatever script is in next page loads with no knowledge of what was in previous page at all. Look into using localStorage to store your theme preference and you will need to use code on every page that needs theme switching

Comment: You cannot change the second php file with a checkbox event on first php file. You will have to put a button and onclick function on first page or use session on first page and put a condition on the session received on second page. You can also use Ajax for dynamically changing the particular page.

Comment: Am I able to do this using php instead?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('#test').click(function(){
    $("#main-div").toggleClass('class-yellow');
  });
  // $('#test').prop('checked', true);  //Checks it
 // $('#test').prop('checked', false);  //Unchecks it
});
```

```css
.class-yellow {
  background:yellow;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main-div'>
  <label for="test">adding style when click</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id='test'>
</div>
```

Comment: this is may helpfull